# get foreach sequence number on an array

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach

I have an array s[],I'm setting it with:

```
    string [] s;
    s = data.Split(',');
```

after I can getting elements from s with foreach:

```
foreach (string c in s)
                    {
                        list.Items.Add(c);  
                    }
```

but I want to write the seqeunce of c near to c value i.e it'll show in list:

```
0 hello
1 world
2 earth
```

I'm not using a counter in foreach,is there another way?

Comment: You want to display its index in the collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a counter. You can use one in foreach, or use a `for` loop and use its counter.

Edit: well if you start with an empty list you *could* use `list.Items.Count` in the loop to print the current count of items in the list although this is *really* not a good way to do that.

```
// ugly
foreach (string c in s)
{
    list.Items.Add(list.Items.Count + " " + c);  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The obvious thing would be to use a regular loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < c.Length; i++) {
  list.Items.Add(i.ToString() + " " + c[i]);
}
```

If you absolutely want to use `foreach` and no counter variable, you can use `Select` to bundle each string with its index:

```
foreach (var c in s.Select((str, i) => new { Value = str, Index = i })) {
  list.Items.Add(c.Index.ToString() + " " + c.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

no there is no other way with given your code.

either you do this:

```
 string [] s= {"0 Hello","1 World", "2 earth"};
 //your simple foreach loop
```

or you do this:

```
int counter=0;
foreach (string c in s)
{
    list.Items.Add(counter++ + " " + c);  
}
```

or change your code, use a for loop

```
foreach (int i=0;i<s.Length;i++)
{
    list.Items.Add(i + " " + c[i]);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks.But I'll not using a counter